# I want to retrieve the next time the notification is triggered

Tags: ios, swift

I use the in local notation repeatInterval, Is it possible to retrieve what time the repeatInterval will work again? I need this to update the counter "how much is left before triggering the notification".

Comment: Which `iOS` versions your app should support?

Comment: @user28434 ios 11, ios 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're targeting `iOS` 10+ you should use [`UNUserNotificationCenter`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter).

`UNUserNotificationCenter` has method [getPendingNotificationRequests(completionHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenter/1649513-getpendingnotificationrequests) that will return in completion handler list of pending notification requests.

Each element of the list is [`UNNotificationRequest`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationrequest) object, which contain property [`trigger`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationrequest/1649635-trigger).

If the trigger is [`UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/untimeintervalnotificationtrigger) or [`UNCalendarNotificationTrigger`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/uncalendarnotificationtrigger) it has method `nextTriggerDate()` which will give you the timepoint when it should be triggered next time.

And it looks like what are you looking for.

Comment: Where I may receive localNotification in this case if didReceive notification in appDelegate was deprecated ?

Comment: @ArtyomVlasenko, [Docs for this method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622930-application) specifically say where it was moved: [```Use userNotificationCenter(_:willPresent:withCompletionHandler:) instead.```](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate/1649518-usernotificationcenter).